# jquery changes quotation mark to &quot after string injection in MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, devextreme

I'm making some tooltip customization of DevExtreeme chart and I want to inject the string into js code in MVC project:

```
.Tooltip(t => t
    .Enabled(true)
    .Location(Model.Tooltip.Location)
    .CustomizeTooltip(@<text>
function(arg) {
return {
text: @Model.Tooltip.Text 
};
}
    </text>)
)
```

The string looks like this:

```
Text = "arg.seriesName + \" years: \" + arg.valueText"
```

but on the output it is:

```
text: arg.seriesName +&quot; years: &quot; + arg.valueText
```

How to fix that? (& didn't help)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have all the information which define the chart in the model. Here is the solution how it should be implemented:

```
Tooltip = new TooltipDataPackage
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Location = ChartTooltipLocation.Edge,
                Text = (item) =>
                {
                    var func = "function(arg) {";
                    func += "return {";
                    func += "text: arg.seriesName + \" wiek: \" + arg.valueText";
                    func += "};";
                    func += "}";
                    return MvcHtmlString.Create(func);
                }
            },
```

The object **TooltipDataPackage** code is defined as follows:

```
public class TooltipDataPackage
{
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public RazorBlock Text { get; set; }
    public ChartTooltipLocation Location { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks strange you keep custom tooltip text within a model. This string `arg.seriesName + \" years: \" + arg.valueText` isn't a common string. It's a JavaScript statement that calculates a string. So, it should not come from a model. Look at this [sample](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/APIDisplayATooltip/Mvc/Light/):

```
.CustomizeTooltip(@<text>
   function (arg) {
      return {
         text: arg.argumentText + "<br />" + arg.valueText
     };
}
</text>)
```

Try to go the same way.